# Why is set $ \bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \{(\frac{k}{n},\frac{1}{n}):k=0,1,\dots,n\} $ closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We have a set:
$$ \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left\{\left(\frac{k}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right):k=0,1,\dots,n\right\} $$

I don't understand the notation, does it mean that when $n=1$ then $k=0$ and both raise equivalently or can we fix one number and change the other?

Also, it says that the set isn't closed. Why not if it's made out of isolated points, shouldn't it be closed?

Comment: @SahibaArora I don't agree. This is a set of points in the plane.

Comment: @SahibaArora I thught that it means points with x and y coordinate. How do I know the difference between the notation of points and intervals in a notation like this?

Comment: @BiliDebili I see my error. To avoid confusion, you should mention the ambient space. (Although it becomes clear because $k\leq n$ ).

Comment: From context mostly... I find it strange that it might be intervals since if it were then you have intervals where the lower bound is greater than the upper bound... They wouldn't bother with $k$ ranging from $0$ on up to $n$ when only $k=0$ or $k=1$ would actually result in a non-empty interval.  For that reason, I agree that it is more likely to be points.

Comment: "*If it's made out of isolated points, shouldn't it be closed?*"  Revisit your definition and look at the example of the set $\{\frac{1}{n}~:~n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ (*as a subset of $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology*) again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am interpreting $(a,b)$ as a point with coordinates $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb R^{2}$.

$(\frac n n,\frac  1n)$ belongs to this set for every $n$ and $(\frac n n,\frac  1n) \to (1,0)$. Since $(1,0)$ does not belong to the set it follows that the set is not closed.  [The second coordinate of every point in the set is strictly positive].

Comment: If I understand correctly it's like we would look at the supremum which is $(1,0)$ but this is not the max ? We can also get this if we do a limit  ?

Comment: Supremum is not defined for sets in the plane. Use the sequential criterion for closedness. A set in metric space is closed iff the limit of any convergent sequence from the set belongs to the set. @BiliDebili

Comment: I understand now. So any more than $R¹$ the supremum and infimum are not defined. Is that right ?

Comment: @BiliDebili We need an ordering of elements of a set to define infimum and supremum. There are sets other than the real line where there are  natural ordeings but there is no natural ordering of points in the plane (or points in $\mathbb R^{k})$

Comment: By points in the plane you define any points that have two or more coordinates?  @Kavi Rama Murthy

Answer (score 2):

Let $$A_n= \left\{\left(\frac{k}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right):k=0,1,\dots,n\right\}.$$ Then $$A_1=\{(0,1),(1,1)\}, A_2=\left\{\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right),\left(\frac12,\frac{1}{2}\right),\left(1,\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\},\ldots$$
The given set is $A:=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n.$ You have $A \ni\left(1,\frac 1n\right)\to(1,0)$ but $(1,0) \notin A,$ so $A$ is not closed.